# Is it usual in anime/manga/japanese to use ブツ as onomatopoeia of mumbling?

Tags: tropes, japanese-language, my-hero-academia

In My Hero Academia we see that when Midoriya is mumbling they use ブツ to symbolize it. Is this the rule for anime/manga/japanese or does it only happen in My Hero Academia?

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted on Japanese.SE: [Is there an onomatopoeia of mumbling in japanese?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59349)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ブツブツ or ぶつぶつ (the same word, just in katakana vs hiragana) is a standard Japanese onomatopoeia for mumbling, muttering, or grumbling to oneself. [This list of Japanese onomatopoeia](https://www.nihongomaster.com/blog/japanese-onomatopoeia-guide/) includes ぶつぶつ in it, along with many other onomatopoeia that show up in manga.